# Warning building a kernel module that uses exported symbols

Tags: linux, gcc, kernel-module

I have two kernel modules (say modA and modB). modA exports a symbol with `EXPORT_SYMBOL(symA)` and modB uses it. I have the header `modA.h` for modA:

```
...
extern void symA(int param);
...
```

and in `modB.c`:

```
#include "modA.h"
...
static int __init modB_init(void)
{
    symA(10);
}
...
```

If i `insmod` modB all works fine, my modB is correctly linked in the kernel and the function `symA` is correctly called. However when i build modB the compiler raises a warning: `symA is undefined`. An LKM is an ELF relocatable so why the compiler raises this warning? How can be this removed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This issue (and how to compile correctly in this case) is explained in http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt

> Sometimes, an external module uses exported symbols from    another
>   external module. kbuild needs to have full knowledge of   all symbols
>   to avoid spitting out warnings about undefined    symbols. Three
>   solutions exist for this situation.
>
> NOTE: The method with a top-level kbuild file is recommended    but may
>   be impractical in certain situations.
>
> Use a top-level kbuild file         If you have two modules, foo.ko and
>   bar.ko, where         foo.ko needs symbols from bar.ko, you can use a
>         common top-level kbuild file so both modules are        compiled in the
>   same build. Consider the following        directory layout:
>
> ```
>   ./foo/ <= contains foo.ko       ./bar/ <= contains bar.ko
>
>   The top-level kbuild file would then look like:
>
>   #./Kbuild (or ./Makefile):          obj-y := foo/ bar/
>
>   And executing
>
>       $ make -C $KDIR M=$PWD
>
>   will then do the expected and compile both modules with         full
> ```
>
> knowledge of symbols from either module.
>
> Use an extra Module.symvers file        When an external module is built,
>   a Module.symvers file         is generated containing all exported symbols
>   which are         not defined in the kernel. To get access to symbols         from
>   bar.ko, copy the Module.symvers file from the         compilation of bar.ko
>   to the directory where foo.ko is      built. During the module build,
>   kbuild will read the      Module.symvers file in the directory of the
>   external      module, and when the build is finished, a new
>         Module.symvers file is created containing the sum of        all symbols
>   defined and not part of the kernel.
>
> Use "make" variable KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS        If it is impractical to
>   copy Module.symvers from      another module, you can assign a space
>   separated list        of files to KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS in your build file.
>         These files will be loaded by modpost during the        initialization of
>   its symbol tables.

Comment: Great! I missed that. Thank you Gossamer!