# Writing a device driver that exports symbols to the kvm module

Tags: drivers, linux-kernel, kvm

I am doing something in the `kvm`. I wrote a device driver module named `logger` in which a function named `print_record()` is defined. I modified some codes in the `kvm` and want to call `print_record()` to put some information in `logger`. Then a userspace application can read `logger` to get information about the status of `kvm`.

This is what I want to do:

For example, I define `print_record()` in file `logger_main.c` and write `EXPORT_SYMBOL(print_record)` in `logger_main.c`, too. In `/arch/x86/kvm/x86.c`, I write `extern print_record(char *)` at the beginning and call `print_record()` someplace in the same file. Then I compile `logger` and `insmod` it.

However, I encounter an error while I compile the `kvm.ko`:

```
make -j 16 modules
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `relocs'.
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CC [M]  arch/x86/kvm/x86.o
  LD [M]  arch/x86/kvm/kvm.o
  LD [M]  arch/x86/kvm/kvm-intel.o
  LD [M]  arch/x86/kvm/kvm-amd.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 2832 modules
  ERROR: "print_record" [arch/x86/kvm/kvm.ko] undefined!
make[1]: *** [__modpost] Error 1
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

I run `cat /proc/kallsyms` and see that the symbol `print_record` is next to 't' which means 'local text'.

I have been stuck to it for one day! I have tried several methods as what someone else does on the Internet but fail.

**Questions:**
What should I do?

Maybe there is something wrong in the Makefile?

Can anyone give a simple but complete example to demonstrate how to call a function defined in an external module in the `kvm`, including the Makefile?

The content of /arch/x86/kvm/Makefile is like this:

```
ccflags-y += -Ivirt/kvm -Iarch/x86/kvm

CFLAGS_x86.o := -I.
CFLAGS_svm.o := -I.
CFLAGS_vmx.o := -I.

KVM := ../../../virt/kvm


kvm-y           += $(KVM)/kvm_main.o $(KVM)/ioapic.o \
                $(KVM)/coalesced_mmio.o $(KVM)/irq_comm.o \
                $(KVM)/eventfd.o $(KVM)/irqchip.o
kvm-$(CONFIG_KVM_DEVICE_ASSIGNMENT) += $(KVM)/assigned-dev.o $(KVM)/iommu.o
kvm-$(CONFIG_KVM_ASYNC_PF)  += $(KVM)/async_pf.o

kvm-y           += x86.o mmu.o emulate.o i8259.o irq.o lapic.o \
               i8254.o cpuid.o pmu.o
kvm-intel-y     += vmx.o
kvm-amd-y       += svm.o

obj-$(CONFIG_KVM)   += kvm.o
obj-$(CONFIG_KVM_INTEL) += kvm-intel.o
obj-$(CONFIG_KVM_AMD)   += kvm-amd.o
```

And the content of my Makefile is like this( I put my codes under `/arch/x86/logger/`)

```
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
    obj-m := logger.o
    logger-objs := logger_main.o

else

KERNELDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)


modules:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
endif


clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.ko *.mod.c
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to answer of:
[Warning building a kernel module that uses exported symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499687/warning-building-a-kernel-module-that-uses-exported-symbols/9499893#9499893)

It is explained in http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt

Sometimes, an external module uses exported symbols from another external module. kbuild needs to have full knowledge of all symbols to avoid spitting out warnings about undefined symbols. Three solutions exist for this situation.

NOTE: The method with a top-level kbuild file is recommended but may be impractical in certain situations.

Use a top-level kbuild file If you have two modules, foo.ko and bar.ko, where foo.ko needs symbols from bar.ko, you can use a common top-level kbuild file so both modules are compiled in the same build.
....

Comment: Don't just copy-paste other answers verbatim - explain *how* it can be used to solve OP's problem